# Understanding Laravel DB::select

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I wrote SQL code to get some database records by year and month. When I execute the code on an SQL console I get records for more than one year but when I copy paste the exact same code in a laravel DB::select it returns the result for just one year. How does this happen? Does the laravel DB::select fetch data diffently.

```
SELECT COUNT(pr.id) AS attendees, DATE_FORMAT(pr.joined_at, "%m") AS month,
DATE_FORMAT(pr.joined_at, "%Y") AS year FROM present pr GROUP BY month, year;
```

I am guessing it's related to the `GROUP BY CLAUSE` but I am not sure.

This is how I am calling `DB::select`

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(pr.id) AS attendees, DATE_FORMAT(pr.joined_at, "%m") AS month,
DATE_FORMAT(pr.joined_at, "%Y") AS year FROM present pr GROUP BY month, year';

$attendance = DB::select($sql);
```

Comment: how you call data using DB::select?

Comment: I just edited the question